# How to cope up with the SAP server maintenance and AppExchange security review?

Tags: appexchange, app, security-review

we are about to submit our app for the security review. The issue would be one of SAP server which we have been using for the app development will be down for maintenance. Since the app relying on the SAP server, will there be any issue for the security review team if they find something not working when they start testing?

Is that possible to communicate with the security team and let them know when would be the SAP maintenance happen so that they can delay their testing?

Experts advice, please. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule office hours with security review and / or add the comments to your submission.

They WILL need the server to be running and operational to validate that the security of the server meets their standards. I would suggest you schedule office hours and discuss a plan with them.

https://security.secure.force.com/security/contact/ohours